# Image change based on scrolling with animation jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a website that I want the logo to change based on scroll height. I also want it to fade in/out between the two logos. I am new to Javascript and jQuery but I have this code working minus the animation:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $(".logo-main").attr("src","IMAGEURL1")
    } else {
         $(".logo-main").attr("src","IMAGEURL2")
    }
 });
```

The logo changes on scroll perfectly. But I want it to fade from the old logo to the new one. I tried this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $(".logo-main").fadeIn().attr("src","IMAGEURL1")
    } else {
         $(".logo-main").fadeOut().attr("src","IMAGEURL2")
    }
});
```

But that causes the "top" logo (the one in the `else`) to fade out before the other logo is ready. It also doesn't come back when you scroll back to the top.

Basically right now it changes to the right image, but it just jumps to it. I want it to fade from one to the other.

P.S. This is in WordPress so I can't control the HTML structure of the logo. That's why I am using `.attr()`.

Comment: Not sure how you're managing to transition from one to the other when they both have the same identifier `.logo-main` or are you using the `IMAGEURL` attribute (which also appears to be identical?), I ask because if you're changing sources on one image tag then you'll need a slightly different approach to the code.

Comment: Ah, they are actually two different URLs. Should have indicated that in my question. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the fading out then fading in effect, you can do something like this:

```
$(".logo-main").fadeOut(function(){
  $(this).attr("src","IMAGEURL").fadeIn();
});
```

The function passed will wait until the logo has faded out before applying the change to the src and fading back in. More info [here on the .fadeOut() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

You will also want to add a conditional to check if the logo's current URL already matches the one you want to change to, or else the logo will fade out and in on every scroll, even if the image remains the same.

Here's some code I came up with. I made the changing of the logo into its own function to avoid repeating code.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

  // Grab the logo's current URL
  var currentURL = $(".logo-main").attr("src");

    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
      // Change logo to IMAGE1 when scrollTop > 400

        // Only change if logo URL does not match IMAGE1
        if(currentURL !== "IMAGE1") { changeLogo("IMAGE1") }

        }
     else {
       // Change logo to IMAGE2

        // Only change if logo URL does not match IMAGE2
        if(currentURL !== "IMAGE2") { changeLogo("IMAGE2") }

    }

    function changeLogo(url){
      $(".logo-main").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).attr("src", url).fadeIn();
      });
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is super close. Upon first loading the logo changes as it should, with fade, but does it twice. This in effect get it backward. So subsequent scrolls work well, fading in and out, but the logos are backward.

FYI I actually decided on a different effect for the logo that I found using CSS only. Here: https://www.impressivewebs.com/stationary-logo-changes-page-scroll-css/ is the link to a tutorial I used. I used this effect because I ended up liking it better, not because I couldn't figure out he jQuery. I knew you guys could do it ;).

Comment: Cool, glad you were able to come to a solution. And thanks for sharing the link, I hadn't seen that before!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can stop it from fading twice !

```
let isScrolling = true; //a variable to stop the .scrollTop >= 400 from repeating
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 400 && isScrolling) {
        $(".logo").fadeOut(400, function(){
          $(".logo").fadeIn(400).attr("src","Image-URL1");  
        });
        isScrolling = false;
      } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 400 && !isScrolling) {
        $(".logo").fadeOut(400, function(){
          $(".logo").fadeIn(400).attr("src","Image-URL2");
        });
        isScrolling = true;
      }
    });
  });
```

Actually when you scroll the scroll event is triggered everytime the screen scrolls down(scrollTop() is calculated for each moved pixel) that is why the image was fading in and fading out multiple times. Hope this helps :)